# A value of type List<SinglePhoto> can't be returned from method because it has a return type of Future<List<SinglePhoto>> как победить? Flutter

Tags: list, foreach, future

Есть следующая функция обрабатывающая список из объектов полученных из json ответа.
data
Обрабатываю foreach для фильтрации по определённым значениям и упаковываю в список объектов

```
Future<List<SinglePhoto>> foreachdata(List data, mpdid) {
    List photoids = [];
    List<SinglePhoto> currentList = [];
    data.forEach((element) {
      if (element.mprdphotoid != null &&
          (!photoids.contains(element.mprdphotoid)) &&
          (element.mprdid == mpdid)) {
        SinglePhoto photo1 =
            SinglePhoto(element.mprdphotoid, element.urlphoto, element.mprdid);
        currentList.add(photo1);
        photoids.add(element.mprdphotoid);
      }
    });
    return currentList;
  }
```

flutter ругается
A value of type List can't be returned from method because it has a return type of Future<List>
Мне нужен именно тип future так как далее я использую futurebuilder widget
Как победить?

Comment: В тексте ошибки содержится всё необходимое. метод `foreachdata` возвращает `Future`, а конструкция `return` в этом методе возвращает `List`. Зачем вы так делаете?

Comment: спасибо, разобрался  убрал future